# Parse query on Main Thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, parse-platform

My iOS app relies heavy on server side data, and just for the launch of it, I need a little bit of information from Parse to get the job done on the app delegate... the issue is I'm making this query on the main thread because otherwise I would use a block or a queue, and immediately after the start of the app, the launch image shows up, then the query starts and the screen goes blank, then the query arrives and the app screen refreshes and is ready to go, but this looks very odd for the user experience and I don't want it to happen..

With the query on the main thread the launch image stays until the data arrives, and it looks much better and the loading time is about 2-3 seconds...

It feels like a bad practice, but...

Any advices?

Regards,

Miguel Rojas Cortés

Comment: Never do network stuff on the main thread, if your device was in a very bad network environment, main thread would block for a long time.

Comment: I agree, you should display your own "loading/launching" launch image as the initial view for your app and then transition to the actual screen once the network task has completed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do a bit more work here

1. Create a separate nib / view controller for the launch screen instead of the using the default iOS one
2. When the launch view controller loaded, starts the request, and don't do any transition just yet. Maybe show some kind of loading indicator there.
3. When all data has arrived, do a transition to the first screen (either fading smoothly or abruptly, IDK).

Doing query on main thread in this case may work 90% of the time, but the other 10%, eg when network is flaky, it's not a nice experience. The app will just hang there, and you got no chance to handle returned errors, since the main thread is blocked.

Answer (score 4):

Don't block the main thread when the app launches. If the network request isn't fast enough, the watchdog will terminate your app and your users will give you 1 star reviews.

Just display your UI with as much info as you have, and show some visual indication that more data is loading. Then update the views when the data arrives.

Also remember to handle the case that the user launches your app with no connectivity. The user should get an appropriate error and an option to retry.